# Lumia 950 unable to open PDF files

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-950, pdf

Today I realized that my lumia 950 is unable to open pdf files. It used to work properly. Anybody knows the reason??

Answer (score 1):

See this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4077675/windows-10-update-kb4077675

They know they broke it, say they will fix it.

FWIW, I have been using the free Adobe PDF reader; it has a few features not present in the browser - you can search for text - but you have to download the file first, which doesn't always work, depending on how a site offers a PDF.

Comment: The link says it applies to Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise. Are you saying the problem applies to regular retail devices as well? I haven't had any problems on my 950.

Comment: Good point about the link, but I think the PDF issue may apply to all Windows 10 Phones having the .248 update.